# How to catch the dynamic xpath id in Rselenium R

Tags: r, xpath, rselenium

I have a problem about one dynamic xpath
I tried to use different way to solve the problem but, I didn't find a great solution yet.

The problem is that I have to use an xpath that, unfortunately, is dynamic and it hasn't never the same length.

Here the part of the html code that generate a click

```
   <div class="field">
        <a onclick="sendGaSearch();" class="ui button rounded" style="background- 
 color: #3fa9f5;" id="id1a2" href="javascript:;">
```

In this case the id is `"id1a2"`, but if I refresh the page the code will be different.

I find this solution, but doesn't work always, because the length of `id="id1a2"` be different.

My solution is:

```
  cod_html<-webElem$getPageSource()
  x<-str_match(cod_html, ".^*ui button rounded ([^\\.]*)\\..*")[,2]
  cod_c<-str_sub(x, 42,47)
  cod_c2<-paste0("//*[@id=",'"', cod_c,'"',"]")
  webElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath",cod_c2)
  webElem$clickElement()
```

The part of the html code that I extract form the page is this:

```
 "\" style=\"background-color: #3fa9f5;\" id=\"id1a2\"
 href=\"javascript:;\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSearch\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t\t\t</form>\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t<script
```

Somebody could help me to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way.

```
  cod_html<-webElem$getPageSource()
  x<-str_extract (string = cod_html, pattern = ("(?<=;\" id=\").*(?=\" href=\"javascript)"))
  cod_c2<-paste0("#",x)
  webElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css selector",value = cod_c2)
  webElem$clickElement()
```

In this way I'm able to catch the dynamic value with different length.

Answer (score 1):

Why create a selector based on a dynamic attribute?

You should always use values from attributes that are not changing and if possible with meaningful text and not something too general, in this case:

```
 //a[@onclick='sendGaSearch()']
```

Or css: `a[href*=sendGaSearch]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
webElem <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", '//a[@onclick="sendGaSearch()"]') but doesn't work. Where I wronge?

Comment: Test the xpath in the page then make sure the element is available or wait for it; What error do you get?

Comment: The error is:
Selenium message:Unable to locate element: //a[@onclick="sendGaSearch()"]

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method

Comment: Please inspect and test the selector then see if its a selector issue(because something is not valid) or if it is an issue related to the page load and not waiting for the element. Also see if it finds multiple elements, if yes your element should be the first found

Comment: Also check for iframes, if the element its inside and iframe you need to switch to the iframe first

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I solved the problem in this way
str_extract (string = x, pattern = ("(? <= \" id = \ "). * (? = \" href = \) ")). In this way I'm able to catch the value in the dynamic way.
Thank you again.