# How do I create a clickable webElement from an elementID in a shadow DOM using RSelenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying download data from this GIS [site](https://data.dhsgis.wi.gov/datasets/covid-19-historical-data-by-county-1/explore), but some of the button elements I need are in a shadow dom.

[image]

My strategy was to run a JS script that uses `shadowRoot.querySelector` to get the "elementID" and use it to point to the button I need to click. I thought I could use `RSelenium::webElement` to create the button elements, but I'm getting an error when I try to click on them.

```
pacman::p_load(RSelenium, glue, dplyr, rvest)

driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"), chromever = "90.0.4430.24")
chrome <- driver$client

wisc_url <- "https://data.dhsgis.wi.gov/datasets/wi-dhs::covid-19-historical-data-by-county/about"

chrome$navigate(url = wisc_url)
Sys.sleep(5)

# open side panel
wisc_dl_panel_button <- chrome$findElement("css selector", "#main-region > div.content-hero > div.content-hero-footer > div.content-footer.flex-row > div.content-footer-right > div.yielded > button")
wisc_dl_panel_button$clickElement()
# sometimes it needs time to create the file
Sys.sleep(120)

# get elementId from shadow DOM
wisc_dlopts_elt_id <- chrome$executeScript("return document.querySelector('hub-download-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('calcite-card').querySelector('calcite-dropdown')")[[1]]
wisc_dlopts_elt <- webElement(elementId = wisc_dlopts_elt_id,
                              browserName = "chrome",
                              port = 4567)
wisc_dlopts_elt$clickElement()

## Error in checkError(res) : 
##  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I don't think it's the particular elementID that I'm using. I tried this create-`webElement` method with other elements that were able to be clicked using the typical `findElement` >> `clickElement` method, and I still get the same error.

BTW I can solve this particular problem through a JS script. But I don't know JS that well, so I'd rather have a RSelenium solution that I can more generally apply if different use cases pop-up in the future.

Comment: @NadPat Link is fixed

Comment: Couldn't find the `Xpath` `css selector`  for the Download button. Maybe try `Docker`

Comment: @NadPat That's the issue with shadow doms.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505485/how-to-catch-the-dynamic-xpath-id-in-rselenium-r

Comment: That person is trying to scrape an object that has an xpath that changes values from time to time. This isn't the same thing. If you find something that you've tested out and works, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_elements` from the `shadowr` package:

```
library(shadowr)
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "host.docker.internal",
  port = 4445 , browser = "chrome")
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)

wisc_url <- "https://data.dhsgis.wi.gov/datasets/wi-dhs::covid-19-vaccination-data-by-county/explore?location=44.718554%2C-89.846850%2C7.23"
remDr$navigate(url = wisc_url)
Sys.sleep(5)

shadow_rd <- shadow(remDr)

wisc_dl_panel_button <- find_elements(shadow_rd, 'button[aria-describedby*="tooltip"]')
wisc_dl_panel_button[[3]]$clickElement()

wisc_dl_panel_button <- find_elements(shadow_rd, 'calcite-button')
wisc_dl_panel_button[[1]]$clickElement()
```

For details and examples please check out my github page https://github.com/ricilandolt/shadowr and https://www.shadowr.org/ (Disclosure: I'm a contributor to this package).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `findElements`?

If you get the CSS or Xpath you can try something like that:

```
frames <- remDr$findElements("css selector", 'your_css')
```

then

```
frames[[1]]$clickElement()
```

That's what I usually do..